# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hello everyone i am using laravel 5 and when I try to add image in it's blade template the following error occurs
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:
i don know what i am doning wrong in it the code i am using is
{{ HTML::image('img/picture.jpg') }}
please help me get over this issue

Comment: What's the path where the image is stored? ./public/img/picture.jpg?

Comment: NotFoundException in RouteCollection.php there is no route defined in route.php file that you are using in your view. So, please post your code.

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel5 you should use !! instead of { like the follow:

```
{!! HTML::image('img/picture.jpg') !!}
```

Comment: Did you see the error ?? It is not the image path issue .